# best way to communicate javascript and C++

Tags: javascript, c++, communication

how  can I communicate javascript  with C++, run some commands, get active processes, but  I didn't find any information on the web.

What I saw is the following links but none helps me:

> http://comunidad.aisoy.es/api/Communication.html
>
> http://www.mosync.com/docs/sdk/js/guides/wormhole/extending-javascript-with-cpp/index.html
>
> http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/ieprogram/article.php/c4399/JavaScript-Calls-from-C.htm

Comment: How about -- just running a C++ program?

Comment: Question's vague.  What program is executing the javascript code?  Does it give your javascript program access to TCP, `exec`, `popen`, `open` for pipes...?  is the C++ program supposed to be already running or started on demand?  Same host or different host?

Comment: i try  to create a windows service in c ++, so when I was called from my javascript, open a program or some script in gstreamer in the same host

Comment: @grijalvaromero I´m repeating Tony D., but:  What program is executing the javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your tiny requirements description, here's a brief overview:

Run your C++ code as a stripped down version of http server, OR better write a C++ apache module. Make your javascript to make AJAX request to the exposed URL by the C++ http server, return the response in JSON/XML.

Just the standard way for your UI (javascript) to speak to the backend (C++)

Comment: thanks for your info, I'll see how to make a module in apache